# Background picture of my app is not showing in other phones only in my phone

Tags: java, android, image, error-handling

Hello I got the following code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/test6"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
```

that represents a login screen with a background picture. When I do the command

./gradlew assembleDebug

to take the apk, I upload it to a cloud server then, and when I download it from my phone the background picture is showing. The problem is that every other phone that downloads the same apk , the background picture is not showing only a white default background. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem about your background image. You should compress your image with 1080x1920 or something like that. If the picture quality is very high, some devices can't be use that picture.